# Magento 2 Frontend form key is not correct

Tags: magento2

I just imported database from an external server into my local developing environment, then i changed the base_url to match with my local URL. I can log into backend using the credentials from that external server, but on frontend, i can't log in without any errors thrown, i was performing some debugging and the form keys on front end are not correct.

I tried saving sessions to db, files, clear all the cookie domains and path in core_config_data but still not working.

Any other suggestions i can take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup of the your local environment DB, try to replace your actual table core_config_data by the old one.

Comment: I'm trying to have the closest database to my external server so that it will be easier to debug, identify issues quickly, so that also includes what configs the external database is having as well, currently i only think that the base url is the only change that i need after importing the core_config_data from external server

Comment: My answer was not a definitive solution but a test to try to localize the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need replace all config domain in core_config_data.
You can try:

```
UPDATE core_config_data
SET `value` = REPLACE(`value`, 'current_domain', 'new_domain')
WHERE `value` LIKE '%current_domain%';
```

Cookie base on domain. check config path

```
web/cookie/cookie_path
web/cookie/cookie_domain
```